# Manage two apps with almost same codebase (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode

> iOS 12, Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 5

I've been working on two apps for the same company, one app is aimed for normal users and the other app is for agencies. Both apps share 80% of code and views (Storyboards or .nib files).
As we were on a hurry at the beginning, I created two Xcode projects and worked on each app separately. Now we're in a refactoring phase, and it's painful that whenever I wanna change something that is common, I have to change it in both projects, which means two code reviews and two new branches and two new merges into master every time.
I read about these three approaches:

1. Targets: But I really don't know if targets solve my problem, and how to merge the two existing projects
2. Workspaces: Don't know if this solves my problem, especially that each project uses CocoaPods (almost the same pods)
3. Building a framework: I tried this approach but using the framework in both apps and on both simulator and device was also a huge pain and I dropped it after I tried to run scripts and figure out a way to make the framework run on both simulators and devices after archiving it.

Does anyone know how to manage such thing without messing both projects?

Comment: I had a similar situation and used different git branches. I could make an update to the shared code and push it to all the branches that needed it.

Comment: target is your thing share almost code and let indivuals files matcha one or another target

Comment: In my company we work with a main app, and then 6 customized appsfor several clients that share 80% of the code , everything is managed with targets.

Comment: @Leemur any idea how I can add an existing project as a target to another project?